# Internal Server Error 500 python flask app on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

When I leave my app [young-harbor-5584.herokuapp.com](http://young-harbor-5584.herokuapp.com) for a day or so, and then try to access it I am seeing the error below.

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

However, when I make a single character change and re-push to Heroku, the app seems to work fine. I know this because I removed a period from a TODO, re-pushed and launched it again.

How can I avoid this? Do I need to set more dynos? 
I think this might be an answer as I see this in the Heroku documents.

> Free dynos will sleep after a half hour of inactivity and they can be
>   active (receiving traffic) for no more than 18 hours a day before
>   going to sleep. If a free dyno is sleeping, and it hasn’t exceeded the
>   18 hours, any web request will wake it. This causes a delay of a few
>   seconds for the first request upon waking. Subsequent requests will
>   perform normally.

Any confirmation or other advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to restart the app first (instead of re-pushing) ? With: heroku ps:restart --app YourAPP

Comment: Does you app uses the filesystem to read/write things ?

Comment: I did not try to restart the app. I'll try that next time but I would want the app up without having to do that. No, there's no filesystem that is being read from or written to. It's all simple from requests.

Comment: If you have a database, make sure it's working first after dyno waking up, and also setup a logging mechanism, in order to diagnose it.